VS Code intellisense for c# not working properly
I am working on a C# project that is still using an older .net version (.net core 2.2) and while basically everything about the project works, I am having some problems with the autocompletion.
When I try to autocomplete any type that is defined within the current file it works without problem and hovering over local variables also shows their definition, but if I try using autocomplete on anything that isn't directly written in the file (like included files via 'using') I simply get not autocomplete suggestions and no type description.
I am using VS Code with the C# extension in it's newest version together with the remote ssh extension to access the project on a server.
Any ideas as to why the intellisense isn't working?

.NET Core 2.2 isn't just an older version, it was reached End Of Life in December 2019. It wasn't even a Long-Time-Support version. The LTS versions were 2.1, 3.1, 6.0 and now, 8.0.Current extensions don't have to support it and problems should be expected

I know that it is no longer supported, but the project is quite big and only used by few users internally so it hasn't been updated yet (but it is planned to be updated in the future)  but I need to do some changes and autocomplete would be helpful even without the new version, so I was wondering if there is some way to get proper autocomplete without having to use a different version.

The current C# extension is uses a completely different backed from the one used back in 2019 (OmniSharp). You can switch back to OmniSharp through configuration. A better solutions would be to upgrade to a supported version. The support lifecycle of .NET Core is well known and published years in advance. The more the migration is delayed, the harder it will be. There are significant differences between LTS versions

Alright, then I'll migrate to a newer version before trying to get it working with some janky workarounds. Thanks!
